# Sharing variables between multiple Dlls in C++

Tags: c++, dll, dllimport, dllexport, data-sharing

I need to share a variables (1000s) between 2 C++ Dlls. How should I do that?

`MyVariables.Dll` contains:

```
int a = 0;
```

`ModifyMyVariables.Dll` contains:

```
extern int a;    
a++; 
// do more stuff with a;
```

What am i supposed to write in the following files?

```
myvariables.h
myvariables.cpp
ModifyMyVariables.h
ModifyMyVariables.cpp
```

Comment: Nobody can debug code that shares thousands of global variables across module boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

You can share data between images (EXE, DLL...) using several fundamental mechanisms (using extern does not work to share data - it only instructs the linker and not the loader!)

1. using import/export symbols (using the standard Import Address Table/Export Table)
2. using [static sections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf9b18xk.aspx) containing your data
3. using [dynamic sections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) containing your data

In your case, I would use the sections. This works pretty good. You must, of course, take care of the synchronisation when accessing (writing) these data from both sides.

Comment: Hi Now I am having a problem: <br> in MyVariable.cpp I wrote the following code. What do I need to do in the other files? <br>        #pragma data_seg(".bb")
    int a = 10000;
    #pragma data_seg()
    #pragma comment(linker, "/section:.bb,RWS")

Comment: See these samples: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/240/How-to-share-a-data-segment-in-a-DLL and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h90dkhs0(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: dammen I still don't get it in  myvariables.dll I declare a global variable in a section- #pragma data_seg(".mysecond")
int test=0 ;
#pragma data_seg()
#pragma comment(linker, "/section:.mysecond,RWS")  in ModifyMyVariables.dll I have extern test; and then test++; this won't compile:  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int test" (?test@@3HA). Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: you don't need extern test anymore! the data are shared on the loader-basis not on the linker-basis anymore!

Comment: Hi but with or wothout the extern I would get a  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol!

Comment: Can you share your code? I guess this is more than the snippet above.